# How am I expected to list my code's copyright and license under GPLv3?

Tags: gpl, gpl-3, license-notice, license-file

Naïve question, I know, but what exactly is the standard for licensing code under GLPv3? Where should I list the copyright and the license? What specifically do I include at the top of each source file? Where and how do I list the license in full?

Comment: Have you read the section at the end of [GPLv3 itself](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html), the one titled "*How to Apply These Terms to Your New Programs*"?

Answer (score 2):

The [GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) comes with a section which reads "How to Apply These Terms to Your New Programs". Quote:

> To do so, attach the following notices to the program. It is safest to attach them to the start of each source file to most effectively state the exclusion of warranty; and each file should have at least the “copyright” line and a pointer to where the full notice is found.

```
<one line to give the program's name and a brief idea of what it does.<br>
Copyright (C) <year>  <name of author>

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
```

> Also add information on how to contact you by electronic and paper mail.

> If the program does terminal interaction, make it output a short notice like this when it starts in an interactive mode:

```
<program>  Copyright (C) <year>  <name of author>
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `show w'.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `show c' for details.
```

> The hypothetical commands `'show w'` and `'show c'` should show the appropriate parts of the General Public License. Of course, your program's commands might be different; for a GUI interface, you would use an “about box”.